# When we need to use curveTo() and setCurve()

Tags: java, java-2d, bezier

In drawing Graphics2D there are 2 ways to draw cubic curve either through `GeneralPath` class and using its methods beginning with `moveTo` and to draw curves with `curveTo`, but i saw also there's another way to draw it, but with another class `CubicCurve2D` then using its methods `setCurve`
so, What's the difference between them ? and when we need to use them ?

Comment: Why not write a simple app. to view the results of various options?  Every time I deal with them, I have to do that (or find the previous app. I wrote to do it!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CubicCurve2D` is a class representing a single curve. Use it when you operate with isolated cubic curves.

`Path2D` (which should be used instead of legacy `GeneralPath`) is a class representing an arbitrary geometric path - sequence of lines, curves and moves etc. Use it when you operate with sequences of connected shapes.